# How to use a variable in libsvm optional arguments?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

In `svmtrain` of libsvm for matlab if I've to set the `wi` option to some constant value I can use this:

```
model = svmtrain(y, X, '-w1 1 -w2 10');
```

But i'm training many classifiers in a loop and I want to set the `wi` parameter using a variable. I tried the following:

```
e1 = 1;
e2 = 10;
model = svmtrain(y, X, '-w1 e1 -w2 e2');
```

Although the above doesn't throw any errors but it has no impact on accuracy i.e, the accuracy remains same as if no weights were passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = ['-w1 ' num2str(e1) '-w2 ' num2str(e2)];
model = svmtrain(y, X, s);
```